# Is it possible to get carrier time using private or public api on iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, time, iphone-privateapi, cellular-network

Is it possible to get the cell network time using public or private API?

Answer (score 0):

This company seems to have an API that does what your looking for

http://www.tuaw.com/2009/01/15/timexchange-offers-a-time-tracking-api/